# horizontal listview not scroll images

Tags: android

thi is my code below for horizontal scrolling  but the problem is  only first 3 images show on screen not scroll to view allimages tellme  how i adjust this?? i found problem is n thid horizontal class  this is my screenshot  [image: http://imgur.com/VwCywjF]

how do I make this custom listview scollable I would appricate any help given.

```
  public class HorizontalListView extends AdapterView<ListAdapter> {

  public boolean mAlwaysOverrideTouch = true;
  protected ListAdapter mAdapter;
  private int mLeftViewIndex = -1;
  private int mRightViewIndex = 0;
  protected int mCurrentX;
  protected int mNextX;
  private int mMaxX = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
  private int mDisplayOffset = 0;
  protected Scroller mScroller;
  private GestureDetector mGesture;
  private Queue<View> mRemovedViewQueue = new LinkedList<View>();
  private OnItemSelectedListener mOnItemSelected;
  private OnItemClickListener mOnItemClicked;
  private OnItemLongClickListener mOnItemLongClicked;
  private boolean mDataChanged = false;
  private boolean mMeasureHeightForVisibleOnly = true;


  public HorizontalListView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    initView();
  }

  private synchronized void initView() {
    mLeftViewIndex = -1;
    mRightViewIndex = 0;
    mDisplayOffset = 0;
    mCurrentX = 0;
    mNextX = 0;
    mMaxX = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
    mScroller = new Scroller(getContext());
    mGesture = new GestureDetector(getContext(), mOnGesture);
  }

  @Override
    public void setOnItemSelectedListener(AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener 
   listener) {
      mOnItemSelected = listener;
    }

  @Override
    public void setOnItemClickListener(AdapterView.OnItemClickListener listener){
      mOnItemClicked = listener;
    }

  @Override
    public void setOnItemLongClickListener(AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener 
 listener) {
      mOnItemLongClicked = listener;
    }

  private DataSetObserver mDataObserver = new DataSetObserver() {

    @Override
      public void onChanged() {
        synchronized(HorizontalListView.this){
          mDataChanged = true;
        }
        invalidate();
        requestLayout();
      }

    @Override
      public void onInvalidated() {
        reset();
        invalidate();
        requestLayout();
      }

  };

  @Override
    public ListAdapter getAdapter() {
      return mAdapter;
    }

  @Override
    public View getSelectedView() {
      //TODO: implement
      return null;
    }

  @Override
    public void setAdapter(ListAdapter adapter) {
      if(mAdapter != null) {
        mAdapter.unregisterDataSetObserver(mDataObserver);
      }
      mAdapter = adapter;
      mAdapter.registerDataSetObserver(mDataObserver);
      reset();
    }

  /**
   * @param visibleOnly - If set to true, then height is calculated
   * only using visible views. If set to false then height is
   * calculated using _all_ views in adapter. Default is true.
   * Be very careful when passing false, as this may result in
   * significant performance hit for larger number of views.
   */
  public void setHeightMeasureMode(boolean visibleOnly) {
    if(mMeasureHeightForVisibleOnly != visibleOnly) {
      mMeasureHeightForVisibleOnly = visibleOnly;
      requestLayout();
    }
  }

  private synchronized void reset(){
    initView();
    removeAllViewsInLayout();
    requestLayout();
  }

  @Override
    public void setSelection(int position) {
      //TODO: implement
    }

  private void addAndMeasureChild(final View child, int viewPos) {
    LayoutParams params = child.getLayoutParams();
    if(params == null) {
      params = new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, 
    LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT);
    }

    addViewInLayout(child, viewPos, params, true);
    child.measure(MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(getWidth(), MeasureSpec.AT_MOST),
        MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(getHeight(), MeasureSpec.AT_MOST));
  }

  @Override
    protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
      super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);

      if(MeasureSpec.getMode(heightMeasureSpec) != MeasureSpec.EXACTLY) {
        int height = 0;

        if(mMeasureHeightForVisibleOnly) {
          int childCount = getChildCount();
          for(int i = 0; i < childCount; i++) {
            View v = getChildAt(i);
            v.measure(MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED, MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED);
            if(v.getMeasuredHeight() > height) {
              height = v.getMeasuredHeight();
            }
          }
        } else {

          /* Traverses _all_ views! Bypasses view recycler! */

          HashMap<Integer, View> mRecycler = new HashMap<Integer, View>();
          int childCount = getAdapter().getCount();
          for(int i = 0; i < childCount; i++) {
            int type = getAdapter().getItemViewType(i);
            View convertView = mRecycler.get(type);
            View v = getAdapter().getView(i, convertView, this);
            mRecycler.put(type, v);

            v.measure(MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED, MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED);
            if(v.getMeasuredHeight() > height) {
              height = v.getMeasuredHeight();
            }
          }
        }

        if(MeasureSpec.getMode(heightMeasureSpec) == MeasureSpec.AT_MOST) {
          int maxHeight = MeasureSpec.getSize(heightMeasureSpec);
          if(maxHeight < height) {
            height = maxHeight;
          }
        }

        setMeasuredDimension(getMeasuredWidth(), height);
      }
    }

  @Override
    protected synchronized void onLayout(boolean changed, int left, int top,
        int right, int bottom) {
      super.onLayout(changed, left, top, right, bottom);

      if(mAdapter == null){
        return;
      }

      if(mDataChanged){
        int oldCurrentX = mCurrentX;
        initView();
        removeAllViewsInLayout();
        mNextX = oldCurrentX;
        mDataChanged = false;
      }

      if(mScroller.computeScrollOffset()){
        int scrollx = mScroller.getCurrX();
        mNextX = scrollx;
      }

      if(mNextX <= 0){
        mNextX = 0;
        mScroller.forceFinished(true);
      }
      if(mNextX >= mMaxX) {
        mNextX = mMaxX;
        mScroller.forceFinished(true);
      }

      int dx = mCurrentX - mNextX;

      removeNonVisibleItems(dx);
      fillList(dx);
      positionItems(dx);

      mCurrentX = mNextX;

      if(!mScroller.isFinished()){
        post(new Runnable(){
            public void run() {
            requestLayout();
            }
            });

      }
    }

  private void fillList(final int dx) {
    int edge = 0;
    View child = getChildAt(getChildCount()-1);
    if(child != null) {
      edge = child.getRight();
    }
    fillListRight(edge, dx);

    edge = 0;
    child = getChildAt(0);
    if(child != null) {
      edge = child.getLeft();
    }
    fillListLeft(edge, dx);


  }

  private void fillListRight(int rightEdge, final int dx) {
    while(rightEdge + dx < getWidth() && mRightViewIndex < mAdapter.getCount()) {

      View child = mAdapter.getView(mRightViewIndex, mRemovedViewQueue.poll(), 
   this);
      addAndMeasureChild(child, -1);
      rightEdge += child.getMeasuredWidth();

      if(mRightViewIndex == mAdapter.getCount()-1) {
        mMaxX = mCurrentX + rightEdge - getWidth();
      }

      if (mMaxX < 0) {
        mMaxX = 0;
      }
      mRightViewIndex++;
    }

  }

  private void fillListLeft(int leftEdge, final int dx) {
    while(leftEdge + dx > 0 && mLeftViewIndex >= 0) {
      View child = mAdapter.getView(mLeftViewIndex, mRemovedViewQueue.poll(), 
    this);
      addAndMeasureChild(child, 0);
      leftEdge -= child.getMeasuredWidth();
      mLeftViewIndex--;
      mDisplayOffset -= child.getMeasuredWidth();
    }
  }

  private void removeNonVisibleItems(final int dx) {
    View child = getChildAt(0);
    while(child != null && child.getRight() + dx <= 0) {
      mDisplayOffset += child.getMeasuredWidth();
      mRemovedViewQueue.offer(child);
      removeViewInLayout(child);
      mLeftViewIndex++;
      child = getChildAt(0);

    }

    child = getChildAt(getChildCount()-1);
    while(child != null && child.getLeft() + dx >= getWidth()) {
      mRemovedViewQueue.offer(child);
      removeViewInLayout(child);
      mRightViewIndex--;
      child = getChildAt(getChildCount()-1);
    }
  }

  private void positionItems(final int dx) {
    if(getChildCount() > 0){
      mDisplayOffset += dx;
      int left = mDisplayOffset;
      for(int i=0;i<getChildCount();i++){
        View child = getChildAt(i);
        int childWidth = child.getMeasuredWidth();
        child.layout(left, 0, left + childWidth, child.getMeasuredHeight());
        left += childWidth;
      }
    }
  }

  public synchronized void scrollTo(int x) {
    mScroller.startScroll(mNextX, 0, x - mNextX, 0);
    requestLayout();
  }

  @Override
    public boolean dispatchTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {
      boolean handled = super.dispatchTouchEvent(ev);
      handled |= mGesture.onTouchEvent(ev);
      return handled;
    }

  protected boolean onFling(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float velocityX,
      float velocityY) {
    synchronized(HorizontalListView.this){
      mScroller.fling(mNextX, 0, (int)-velocityX, 0, 0, mMaxX, 0, 0);
    }
    requestLayout();

    return true;
  }

  protected boolean onDown(MotionEvent e) {
    mScroller.forceFinished(true);
    return true;
  }

  private OnGestureListener mOnGesture = new 
   GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener() {

    @Override
      public boolean onDown(MotionEvent e) {
        return HorizontalListView.this.onDown(e);
      }

    @Override
      public boolean onFling(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float velocityX,
          float velocityY) {
        return HorizontalListView.this.onFling(e1, e2, velocityX, velocityY);
      }

    @Override
      public boolean onScroll(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2,
          float distanceX, float distanceY) {

        synchronized(HorizontalListView.this){
          mNextX += (int)distanceX;
        }
        requestLayout();

        return true;
      }

    @Override
      public boolean onSingleTapConfirmed(MotionEvent e) {
        Rect viewRect = new Rect();
        for(int i=0;i<getChildCount();i++){
          View child = getChildAt(i);
          int left = child.getLeft();
          int right = child.getRight();
          int top = child.getTop();
          int bottom = child.getBottom();
          viewRect.set(left, top, right, bottom);
          if(viewRect.contains((int)e.getX(), (int)e.getY())){
            if(mOnItemClicked != null){
              mOnItemClicked.onItemClick(HorizontalListView.this, child, 
  mLeftViewIndex + 1 + i, mAdapter.getItemId( mLeftViewIndex + 1 + i ));
            }
            if(mOnItemSelected != null){
              mOnItemSelected.onItemSelected(HorizontalListView.this, child, 
   mLeftViewIndex + 1 + i, mAdapter.getItemId( mLeftViewIndex + 1 + i ));
            }
            break;
          }

        }
        return true;
      }

    @Override
      public void onLongPress(MotionEvent e) {
        Rect viewRect = new Rect();
        int childCount = getChildCount();
        for (int i = 0; i < childCount; i++) {
          View child = getChildAt(i);
          int left = child.getLeft();
          int right = child.getRight();
          int top = child.getTop();
          int bottom = child.getBottom();
          viewRect.set(left, top, right, bottom);
          if (viewRect.contains((int) e.getX(), (int) e.getY())) {
            if (mOnItemLongClicked != null) {
              mOnItemLongClicked.onItemLongClick(HorizontalListView.this, child, 
  mLeftViewIndex + 1 + i, mAdapter.getItemId(mLeftViewIndex + 1 + i));
            }
            break;
          }

        }
      }

  };



}
```

Comment: Please post only the relevant code and any relevant xml files

Comment: this is releven code bcoz if i usd other HorizontalListview  code is show only text  but that are scrolling